# how can i store values to a href link multiple values in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to store lots of values to this link in order to pass the values to aspx page in this style how can i increase the number of values .

```
htmlBody = string.Format(" Hi "+userName+ 
"\n Thank you for creating an account with RSS MANAGEMENT SYSTEM \n </ br>" + 
"Please click the below link to activate your account <br />" + 
"<a href='http://localhost:2386/ActivateUser.aspx?userName{0}&Id={1}'>Activate {0} </a>",
UName, user_name);
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking how can you increase the number of tokens to replace in your format string?

Answer (score 1):

So you mean like this:

```
var someothervalue=1:
string.format("<a href='http://localhost:2386/ActivateUser.aspx?userName{0}&Id={1}'>Activate {0} </a>{2}", 
UName, user_name,someothervalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var values = new Dictionary<string,string>{ 
                                                {"username", user_name},
                                                {"id", UName},
                                                {"otherparam", "lalala"}
                                         };

var queryString = string.Join("&" + values.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));

var link = string.format("<a href='http://localhost:2386/ActivateUser.aspx?{0}'>Activate {1} </a>", queryString, user_name);
```

Comment: how can i get it from aspx side?

Comment: what do you mean with "get it"? in the "ActivateUser.aspx"? Request.QueryString["username"], for example